# Python Pandas propagate value untill condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lwJg.png)

I have this DataFrame (look picture)

If green column (`dataframe.Signal`) is 1, I have red column (`dataframe.Level`) that is equal to a certain value in our example 1088.50, otherwise `dataframe.Level` will be Nan

Now I want to propagate the red value (`dataframe.Level`) as long as it is lower or equal than brown value, (`dataframe.Brown`)

When `dataframe.Brown` is lower than red value `dataframe.Level` must be equal to red value for the last time, then it must go back to nan, just like in the photo.

how can i do something like this? **I tried using normal for lops but this dataframe contains 6 millions row and it is too slow.**

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

```
left = df.loc[df["Signal"] == 1].index
right = df.loc[df["Brown"] - df["Level"].ffill() < 0] \ 
          .groupby(df["Signal"].cumsum(), as_index=False) \
          .nth(0).index
subsets = pd.cut(df.index, pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(left, right, closed="both"))
df = df.groupby(subsets).ffill()
```

Input data:

```
      Brown  Signal    Level
0   1089.00       0      NaN
1   1089.00       0      NaN
2   1088.50       0      NaN
3   1088.50       0      NaN
4   1088.50       1  1088.50  # 1088.50 <= start here (4)
5   1088.50       0      NaN  # 1088.50
6   1088.50       0      NaN  # 1088.50
7   1088.50       0      NaN  # 1088.50
8   1088.50       0      NaN  # 1088.50
9   1088.75       0      NaN  # 1088.50
10  1088.50       0      NaN  # 1088.50
11  1088.25       0      NaN  # 1088.50 <= stop here (11)
12  1088.50       0      NaN
13  1088.25       1  1088.25  # 1088.25 <= start here (13)
14  1088.50       0      NaN  # 1088.25
15  1088.50       0      NaN  # 1088.25
16  1088.00       0      NaN  # 1088.25 <= stop here (16)
17  1088.50       0      NaN
18  1088.75       0      NaN
19  1088.50       0      NaN
20  1088.25       0      NaN
21  1088.50       0      NaN
```

1. Find start indexes (left interval) <= [4, 13]

```
>>> left = df.loc[df["Signal"] == 1].index
>>> left
Int64Index([4, 13], dtype='int64')
```

2. Find stop indexes (right interval) <= [11, 16]

```
>>> right = df.loc[df["Brown"] - df["Level"].ffill() < 0] \ 
              .groupby(df["Signal"].cumsum(), as_index=False) \
              .nth(0).index
>>> right
Int64Index([11, 16], dtype='int64')
```

3. Extract all subsets <= [(4, 11), (13, 16)]

```
>>> subsets = pd.cut(df.index, pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(left, right, closed="both"))
>>> list(subsets)
[nan,
 nan,
 nan,
 nan,
 Interval(4.0, 11.0, closed='both'),
 Interval(4.0, 11.0, closed='both'),
 Interval(4.0, 11.0, closed='both'),
 Interval(4.0, 11.0, closed='both'),
 Interval(4.0, 11.0, closed='both'),
 Interval(4.0, 11.0, closed='both'),
 Interval(4.0, 11.0, closed='both'),
 Interval(4.0, 11.0, closed='both'),
 nan,
 Interval(13.0, 16.0, closed='both'),
 Interval(13.0, 16.0, closed='both'),
 Interval(13.0, 16.0, closed='both'),
 Interval(13.0, 16.0, closed='both'),
 nan,
 nan,
 nan,
 nan,
 nan]
```

4. Fill `Level` value along each interval:

```
>>> df.groupby(subsets).ffill()
      Brown  Signal    Level
0   1089.00       0      NaN
1   1089.00       0      NaN
2   1088.50       0      NaN
3   1088.50       0      NaN
4   1088.50       1  1088.50
5   1088.50       0  1088.50
6   1088.50       0  1088.50
7   1088.50       0  1088.50
8   1088.50       0  1088.50
9   1088.75       0  1088.50
10  1088.50       0  1088.50
11  1088.25       0  1088.50
12  1088.50       0      NaN
13  1088.25       1  1088.25
14  1088.50       0  1088.25
15  1088.50       0  1088.25
16  1088.00       0  1088.25
17  1088.50       0      NaN
18  1088.75       0      NaN
19  1088.50       0      NaN
20  1088.25       0      NaN
21  1087.75       0      NaN
```

Comment: it doesnt seems to work because left and right have different length,
if you are willing to help me please contact via telegram @claudio314 I will donate you as much as you want via paypal. thanks.

Comment: Post an example which it doesn't work, please.

Comment: "left and right must have the same length"
this is the error that i get when i run the above script

Comment: but it works on input data because left and right have the same length. To help you I need an example which it doesn't work.

Comment: I still didn`t understand what RIGHT is doing,
I see you want to take the indexes that have brown lower than filled level, and this is correct assumption,
I dont understand what this does and i think here is the problem .groupby(df["Signal"].cumsum(), as_index=False).nth(0)
i am very sure the problem is in RIGHT because it doesnt do what it is supposed to do,
remember that i want to propagate only after signal is 1 and i want to stop propagation just when brown is lower than filled level

Comment: I think I understand where is the problem,

RIGHT is shorter than LEFT, because sometimes signal is 1 but brown never goes lower than filled level, so the filling continues untill a new signal comes out with a new level,

Comment: I didn't think of that. I don't know how to do it. Maybe @jezrael or other one can help you if they see your post.